# Minecraft Bedrock player save file locations

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am working with a server here. There are many players in the server, and I want to see where the player-data files are stored. According to this link ( [How can I get the inventory of another player on a LAN World?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303701/how-can-i-get-the-inventory-of-another-player-on-a-lan-world) ), there should be a folder named "players" in the world's save folder. However, I only see a folder called "db" (with many `.ldb` files) and also the files `level.dat`, `level.dat_old`, and `levelname.txt`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the Windows 10 edition, the explaination you found is for the Java edition.

The file system works very differently between those editions and the player data (at least for the local player) in the Windows 10 edition seems to be inside the db folder, in the *.log file. I have not been able to successfully do a targeted change, but deleting the log file does delete my inventory.

Comment: Thanks! I see that the  *.log seems to be an nbt file. I'll try poking around with it later tonight.

Comment: How did it go for you? Did you manage to change the inventory the way you want? If so, then you could add that information to the answer (How you did it).

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work out. I tried opening the file with python using nbtlib, but it told me that there was an invalid byte. I also tried cutting off bytes from the start of the file and feeding that into nbtlib, but it didn't work out either.

Comment: The bedrock version does not seem to use ntb at all, so it is likely some different format. It looks like you can read the inventory as real words, but changing the entries did not alter my inventory. I used the standard windows text editor to look at it.

Comment: Did anyone figure this out yet?

Answer (score -1):

Windows Save Location: `%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang`

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Then Copy > `%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang`
- Paste it in the run window
- Press OK

Android Save Location: `storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mojang.minecraftpe/files/games/com.mojang`

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which is about the file format of that directory once it is found, not where to find it.